# Date is not parsing properly in Perl code

Tags: linux, perl, date

I have a below script which should fetch last 2 days date.

I found 2 different methods but one is working fine(`array2`) and one is not(`array1`).

Below is my script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my (@array1, @array2);

$array1[1]  = `TZ=GMT+24 date +%Y\-%m\-%d`; chomp $array1[1];
$array1[2]  = `TZ=GMT+48 date +%Y\-%m\-%d`; chomp $array1[2];

print "array1:\n".Dumper(\@array1);

$array2[1] = `date --date='1 day ago' "+%Y-%m-%d"`; chomp $array2[1];
$array2[2] = `date --date='2 day ago' "+%Y-%m-%d"`; chomp $array2[2];

print "array2:\n".Dumper(\@array2);
```

In both the arrays it should have date which is past 2 days.
For eg: If today is `2020-08-14`, it should print array elements as `2020-08-13` & `2020-08-12`.

In `array2` its printing as expected, but `array1` its not (correct me its the right way to fetch the past date using `TZ`).

I am getting below result:

```
array1:
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          '2020-08-13',
          '2020-08-13'
        ];
array2:
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          '2020-08-13',
          '2020-08-12'
        ];
```

Also there is `undef` as first element in each array. Why it is so?

I am running this script in `Linux version 2.6.32`.

Comment: Why are you shelling out to make these dates? There are plenty of tools that come with core Perl to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @simbabque, I understand that and I would always use Perl to do so. Since these script were already written in this way, trying to understand why its not parsing properly.

Comment: Even if it added 24/48 hours, it would would add 24/48 hours to the current date of someone at UTC+0, not 24/48 hours to the local current date. You seem to have forgotten it's not the same date every around the world!

Comment: @ikegami In that case atleast it should change the date right? I was thinking `@array1` should produce same result as `@array2`. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do math with the `TZ` variable other than adjustments within +-24 hours. From the documentation for [TZ](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html), note:

> std offset
>
> The std string specifies the name of the time zone. It must be three or more characters long and must not contain a leading colon, embedded digits, commas, nor plus and minus signs. There is no space character separating the time zone name from the offset, so these restrictions are necessary to parse the specification correctly.
>
> The offset specifies the time value you must add to the local time to get a Coordinated Universal Time value. It has syntax like [+|-]hh[:mm[:ss]]. This is positive if the local time zone is west of the Prime Meridian and negative if it is east. The hour must be between 0 and 24, and the minute and seconds between 0 and 59.

As noted, Perl has simple, fool-proof ways to manipulate times. Your code forks an external shell process to achieve what could be done natively and thus isn't desirable, although workable for the second method choice with GNU's version of `date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for z in `seq 1 36`; do echo -n "$z - "; TZ="GMT+$z" date; done
1 - Fri 14 Aug 12:01:32 GMT 2020
2 - Fri 14 Aug 11:01:32 GMT 2020
3 - Fri 14 Aug 10:01:32 GMT 2020
4 - Fri 14 Aug 09:01:32 GMT 2020
5 - Fri 14 Aug 08:01:32 GMT 2020
6 - Fri 14 Aug 07:01:32 GMT 2020
7 - Fri 14 Aug 06:01:32 GMT 2020
8 - Fri 14 Aug 05:01:32 GMT 2020
9 - Fri 14 Aug 04:01:32 GMT 2020
10 - Fri 14 Aug 03:01:32 GMT 2020
11 - Fri 14 Aug 02:01:32 GMT 2020
12 - Fri 14 Aug 01:01:32 GMT 2020
13 - Fri 14 Aug 00:01:32 GMT 2020
14 - Thu 13 Aug 23:01:32 GMT 2020
15 - Thu 13 Aug 22:01:32 GMT 2020
16 - Thu 13 Aug 21:01:32 GMT 2020
17 - Thu 13 Aug 20:01:32 GMT 2020
18 - Thu 13 Aug 19:01:32 GMT 2020
19 - Thu 13 Aug 18:01:32 GMT 2020
20 - Thu 13 Aug 17:01:32 GMT 2020
21 - Thu 13 Aug 16:01:32 GMT 2020
22 - Thu 13 Aug 15:01:32 GMT 2020
23 - Thu 13 Aug 14:01:32 GMT 2020
24 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
25 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
26 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
27 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
28 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
29 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
30 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
31 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
32 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
33 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
34 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
35 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
36 - Thu 13 Aug 13:01:32 GMT 2020
```

Your first approach seems to work up to 24 hours. As it makes no sense to have a time difference of more than 24 hours, I expect that `date` is intelligent enough to cap the difference at 24 hours.